# Linux cross-platform mobile app development tools in 2015

Tags: mobile, cross-platform

I am looking for an Cross-platform mobile app development tool that works on Linux. I have tried cordova and intel xdk but none of them works so okay like they are on windows. What are the the best cross-platform mobile app development tools in 2015?
edit: especially recommendations with easily admob and push notification integration would be so helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First I need to clarify some information:

Cordova, also know as PhoneGap, is a bridge to build Hybrid applications and enable you to run in various platforms such as Android, iOS, WP8, Firefox OS, Tizen and others using Javascript + Html5 + css3.

Intel XDK relies on Cordova. Intel XDK is most an easy way to  use cordova since it gives you the IDE and the ability to build your application on the cloud instead on your machine. And I am using it on Linux for almost a year without a problem, may you can tell what kind of problems did you have?

So, for now, my answer is that the best cross  platform to build hybrid applications is Cordova and you can use Kendo Ui, JQuery Mobile, Ionic, Etc.

If you are looking for an easy way to use admob and push notifications my advice is that you gonna need to use an paid platform such as Telerik Platform($$$) or Ionic($? Free??). In this field Intel XDK did not helped me, once I had to built these features on my way because the support for them in Intel XDK is only if you are using the Legacy Platform (don't do it!).

It's worth take a look at NativeScript (BETA) which currently(2015-03) promises a cross-platform to build native applications Android, iOS and Windows Phone using a code in JS / Typescript.

http://cordova.apache.org/

https://www.nativescript.org

Comment: Hi @André Duarte The problem about XDK is also known by Intel it crashes a lot when you have heavy work. They say it is hard a problem not easy to fix. And I understand your point about cordova but intel XDK not only relies on cordova, it is a feature. You can also use XDK without cordova. And thanks for advices I have never heard of nativescripts, I am gonna give it a try. But at the end of the day I guess I have to stick with Cordova.

Comment: @zahedae, You are right, does not rely on Cordova, instead it uses cordova if you want. NativeScript is in beta and we don't know what future reserves.  It's worth to mention that the learning curve on Nativescript is bigger than in cordova. By the way, if instead of me you are an Javascript Ninja it will be no problem.